# Attaching an EBS volume to AWS Batch Compute Environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, aws-batch, spot-instances

I want to set up AWS Batch running few python scripts to do some batch operations on file fetched from S3 and post processing they need to be saved to a volume.

For this I want to configure compute environments in AWS batch.

I wish to use spot instances but i need my EBS volume to be there even after instance is terminated and if new instance is spin up it has to mount same volume as used before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a instance-template, provide a bootstrap script, for the mentioned case something like:

```
sudo mkdir -p /<any directory name where volume will be mounted eg: dir>

aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id <volume_id> --instance-id $(wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --device /dev/sdf

sudo mount /dev/sdf /<above mentioned dir rg :dir>
```

in AWS batch definition, use the above template to launch your ec2 machine.